# Filling a matrix using parallel processing in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to speed up the solution time for a dynamic programming problem in Julia (v. 0.5.0), via parallel processing. The problem involves choosing the optimal values for every element of a 1073 x 19 matrix at every iteration, until successive matrix differences fall within a tolerance. I thought that, within each iteration, filling in the values for each element of the matrix could be parallelized. However, I'm seeing a huge performance degradation using `SharedArray`, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to approach parallel processing for this problem.

I construct the arguments for the function below:

```
    est_params = [.788,.288,.0034,.1519,.1615,.0041,.0077,.2,0.005,.7196]

    r          = 0.015
    tau        = 0.35
    rho        =est_params[1]
    sigma      =est_params[2]
    delta      = 0.15
    gamma      =est_params[3]
    a_capital  =est_params[4]
    lambda1    =est_params[5]
    lambda2    =est_params[6]
    s          =est_params[7]
    theta      =est_params[8]
    mu         =est_params[9]
    p_bar_k_ss  =est_params[10]
    beta  = (1+r)^(-1)
    sigma_range = 4
    gz = 19 
    gp = 29 
    gk = 37 

    lnz=collect(linspace(-sigma_range*sigma,sigma_range*sigma,gz))
    z=exp(lnz)

    gk_m = fld(gk,2)
    # Need to add mu somewhere to k_ss
    k_ss =  (theta*(1-tau)/(r+delta))^(1/(1-theta))
    k=cat(1,map(i->k_ss*((1-delta)^i),collect(1:gk_m)),map(i->k_ss/((1-delta)^i),collect(1:gk_m)))
    insert!(k,gk_m+1,k_ss)
    sort!(k)
    p_bar=p_bar_k_ss*k_ss
    p = collect(linspace(-p_bar/2,p_bar,gp))

    #Tauchen
    N     = length(z)
    Z     = zeros(N,1)
    Zprob = zeros(Float32,N,N)

    Z[N]  = lnz[length(z)]
    Z[1]  = lnz[1]

    zstep = (Z[N] - Z[1]) / (N - 1)

    for i=2:(N-1)
        Z[i] = Z[1] + zstep * (i - 1)
    end

    for a = 1 : N
        for b = 1 : N
          if b == 1
              Zprob[a,b] = 0.5*erfc(-((Z[1] - mu - rho * Z[a] + zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2))
          elseif b == N
              Zprob[a,b] = 1 - 0.5*erfc(-((Z[N] - mu - rho * Z[a] - zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2))
          else
              Zprob[a,b] = 0.5*erfc(-((Z[b] - mu - rho * Z[a] + zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2)) -
                           0.5*erfc(-((Z[b] - mu - rho * Z[a] - zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2))
          end
        end
    end
    # Collecting tauchen results in a 2 element array of linspace and array; [2] gets array
    # Zprob=collect(tauchen(gz, rho, sigma, mu, sigma_range))[2]
    Zcumprob=zeros(Float32,gz,gz)
    # 2 in cumsum! denotes the 2nd dimension, i.e. columns
    cumsum!(Zcumprob, Zprob,2)


    gm = gk * gp

    control=zeros(gm,2)
    for i=1:gk
        control[(1+gp*(i-1)):(gp*i),1]=fill(k[i],(gp,1))
        control[(1+gp*(i-1)):(gp*i),2]=p
    end
    endog=copy(control)

    E=Array(Float32,gm,gm,gz)
    for h=1:gm
       for m=1:gm
           for j=1:gz
             # set the nonzero net debt indicator
              if endog[h,2]<0
                 p_ind=1

              else
                 p_ind=0
              end

               # set the investment indicator
                if (control[m,1]-(1-delta)*endog[h,1])!=0
                   i_ind=1
                else
                   i_ind=0
                end

                E[m,h,j] = (1-tau)*z[j]*(endog[h,1]^theta) + control[m,2]-endog[h,2]*(1+r*(1-tau))  +
                    delta*endog[h,1]*tau-(control[m,1]-(1-delta)*endog[h,1]) -
                     (i_ind*gamma*endog[h,1]+endog[h,1]*(a_capital/2)*(((control[m,1]-(1-delta)*endog[h,1])/endog[h,1])^2)) +
                    s*endog[h,2]*p_ind
                elem = E[m,h,j]
                if E[m,h,j]<0
                    E[m,h,j]=elem+lambda1*elem-.5*lambda2*elem^2
                else
                    E[m,h,j]=elem
                end
            end
        end
     end
```

I then constructed the function with serial processing. The two `for` loops iterate through each element to find the largest value in a 1072-sized (=the `gm` scalar argument in the function) array:

```
function dynam_serial(E,gm,gz,beta,Zprob)
    v           = Array(Float32,gm,gz )
    fill!(v,E[cld(gm,2),cld(gm,2),cld(gz,2)])

    Tv          = Array(Float32,gm,gz)

    # Set parameters for the loop
    convcrit = 0.0001   # chosen convergence criterion
    diff = 1          # arbitrary initial value greater than convcrit

    while diff>convcrit
      exp_v=v*Zprob'

      for h=1:gm
        for j=1:gz
          Tv[h,j]=findmax(E[:,h,j] + beta*exp_v[:,j])[1]
        end
      end

      diff = maxabs(Tv - v)
      v=copy(Tv)
    end
end
```

Timing this, I get:

```
@time dynam_serial(E,gm,gz,beta,Zprob)

> 106.880008 seconds (91.70 M allocations: 203.233 GB, 15.22% gc time)
```

Now, I try using Shared Arrays to benefit from parallel processing. Note that I reconfigured the iteration so that I only have one `for` loop, rather than two. I also use `v=deepcopy(Tv)`; otherwise, `v` is copied as an `Array` object, rather than a `SharedArray`:

```
function dynam_parallel(E,gm,gz,beta,Zprob)
    v           = SharedArray(Float32,(gm,gz),init = S -> S[Base.localindexes(S)] = myid() )
    fill!(v,E[cld(gm,2),cld(gm,2),cld(gz,2)])

    # Set parameters for the loop
    convcrit = 0.0001   # chosen convergence criterion
    diff = 1          # arbitrary initial value greater than convcrit

    while diff>convcrit
      exp_v=v*Zprob'
      Tv          = SharedArray(Float32,gm,gz,init = S -> S[Base.localindexes(S)] = myid() )

      @sync @parallel for hj=1:(gm*gz)
         j=cld(hj,gm)
         h=mod(hj,gm)
         if h==0;h=gm;end;

         @async Tv[h,j]=findmax(E[:,h,j] + beta*exp_v[:,j])[1]
      end

      diff = maxabs(Tv - v)
      v=deepcopy(Tv)
    end
end
```

Timing the parallel version; and using a 4-core 2.5 GHz I7 processor with 16GB of memory,  I get:

```
addprocs(3)
@time dynam_parallel(E,gm,gz,beta,Zprob)

> 164.237208 seconds (2.64 M allocations: 201.812 MB, 0.04% gc time)
```

Am I doing something incorrect here? Or is there a better way to approach parallel processing in Julia for this particular problem? I've considered using Distributed Arrays, but it's difficult for me to see how to apply them to the present problem.

**UPDATE**:
Per @DanGetz and his helpful comments, I turned instead to trying to speed up the serial processing version. I was able to get performance down to `53.469780 seconds (67.36 M allocations: 103.419 GiB, 19.12% gc time)` through:

1) Upgrading to 0.6.0 (saved about 25 seconds), which includes the helpful `@views` macro.

2) Preallocating the main array I'm trying to fill in (`Tv`), per the section on Preallocating Outputs in the Julia Performance Tips: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/. (saved another 25 or so seconds)

The biggest remaining slow-down seems to be coming from the `add_vecs` function, which sums together subarrays of two larger matrices. I've tried devectorizing and using BLAS functions, but haven't been able to produce better performance.

In any event, the improved code for `dynam_serial` is below:

```
function add_vecs(r::Array{Float32},h::Int,j::Int,E::Array{Float32},exp_v::Array{Float32},beta::Float32)

  @views r=E[:,h,j] + beta*exp_v[:,j]
  return r
end


function dynam_serial(E::Array{Float32},gm::Int,gz::Int,beta::Float32,Zprob::Array{Float32})
    v           = Array{Float32}(gm,gz)
    fill!(v,E[cld(gm,2),cld(gm,2),cld(gz,2)])
    Tv          = Array{Float32}(gm,gz)
    r           = Array{Float32}(gm)

    # Set parameters for the loop
    convcrit = 0.0001   # chosen convergence criterion
    diff = 1          # arbitrary initial value greater than convcrit

    while diff>convcrit
      exp_v=v*Zprob'

      for h=1:gm
        for j=1:gz
          @views Tv[h,j]=findmax(add_vecs(r,h,j,E,exp_v,beta))[1]
        end
      end

      diff = maximum(abs,Tv - v)
      v=copy(Tv)
    end
    return Tv
end
```

Comment: Perhaps optimizing the non-parallel version first? The matrix has ~20,000 elements i.e. 160KB but the timing shows it allocates millions of times and about a 1000 times the matrix size. There should be room for big improvements. Also, using the latest Julia version and vectorized dot-notation is a big bonus.

Comment: What does `dynam_serial` return? Currently you can optimize it by simply not running it, as it has no external effect and returns nothing

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your comments.

Comment: I truncated the function just to illustrate the problem. Ultimately, it returns the matrix `v` (shown) as well as a decision rule (not shown), which are later used in simulations (also not shown). I'll try to optimize the non-parallel version first, as best I can, and also upgrade to the latest Julia version.  Also note that while the matrix is ~20,000 elements, those 20,000 elements are filled in over many iterations until convergence.

Comment: Although the iterations fill the matrix, they should avoid reallocating it. It is best to truncate a function and add the return statement. As the compiler might really decide, and rightly, to optimize away the entire example. A smart compiler would.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment! Upgrading to 6.0 and adding the `@views` macro ahead of the `Tv[h,j]=findmax(E[:,h,j] + beta*exp_v[:,j])[1]` expression  brought performance to `>80.965610 seconds (67.39 M allocations: 200.798 GiB, 22.11% gc time)` for `dynam_serial`. However, I'm struggling to wring some performance improvement via reallocation. Putting `return v` at the end didn't provide any improvement; I also tried to pre-allocate the `Tv` matrix by following the example under Pre-allocating Outputs here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/.

Comment: Specifically, I created a separate in-place function that performed the `findmax` operation on each element of the `Tv` matrix, within each iteration, which then replaced `Tv[h,j]=findmax(E[:,h,j] + beta*exp_v[:,j])[1]` in the main function. I actually saw a performance degradation when I did this; I also tried additionally putting a `return` statement after the `while` loop, to no avail.

Comment: Dan, your comments were very helpful. I've continued to work on pre-allocating the arrays used in each iteration, and have gotten performance to `60.107114 seconds (67.36 M allocations: 103.419 GiB, 18.49% gc time`. I'll keep at it! Thanks very much.

Comment: If you add the updated `dynam_serial` to the question. Perhaps there may be suggestions for more optimization.

Comment: Dan, I provided an update above. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `add_vecs` seems to be the critical function, writing an explicit `for` loop could offer more optimization. How does the following benchmark:

```
function add_vecs!(r::Array{Float32},h::Int,j::Int,E::Array{Float32},
                  exp_v::Array{Float32},beta::Float32)
    @inbounds for i=1:size(E,1)
        r[i]=E[i,h,j] + beta*exp_v[i,j]
    end
    return r
end
```

**UPDATE**

To continue optimizing `dynam_serial` I have tried to remove more allocations. The result is:

```
function add_vecs_and_max!(gm::Int,r::Array{Float64},h::Int,j::Int,E::Array{Float64},
                           exp_v::Array{Float64},beta::Float64)
    @inbounds for i=1:gm            
        r[i] = E[i,h,j]+beta*exp_v[i,j]
    end
    return findmax(r)[1]
end

function dynam_serial(E::Array{Float64},gm::Int,gz::Int,
                      beta::Float64,Zprob::Array{Float64})
    v           = Array{Float64}(gm,gz)
    fill!(v,E[cld(gm,2),cld(gm,2),cld(gz,2)])
    r           = Array{Float64}(gm)
    exp_v       = Array{Float64}(gm,gz)

    # Set parameters for the loop
    convcrit = 0.0001   # chosen convergence criterion
    diff = 1.0 # arbitrary initial value greater than convcrit
    while diff>convcrit
        A_mul_Bt!(exp_v,v,Zprob)
        diff = -Inf
        for h=1:gm
            for j=1:gz
                oldv = v[h,j]
                newv = add_vecs_and_max!(gm,r,h,j,E,exp_v,beta)
                v[h,j]= newv
                diff = max(diff, oldv-newv, newv-oldv)
            end
        end
    end
    return v
end
```

Switching the functions to use Float64 should increase speed (as CPUs are inherently optimized for 64-bit word lengths). Also, using the mutating `A_mul_Bt!` directly saves another allocation. Avoiding the `copy(...)` by switching the arrays `v` and `Tv`.

How do these optimizations improve your running time?

**2nd UPDATE**

Updated the code in the UPDATE section to use `findmax`. Also, changed `dynam_serial` to use `v` without `Tv`, as there was no need to save the old version except for the `diff` calculation, which is now done inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that brought the time down to around 40 seconds: `40.443503 seconds (30.77 M allocations: 51.280 GiB, 13.13% gc time)`.  I made one additional change, which was to remove `r = Vector{Float32}(size(E,1))` from `add_vecs`, as I'd already preallocated it in `dynam_serial` and made it an argument of `add_vecs`.  That brought the time down to around 26 secons: `26.337123 seconds (18.58 M allocations: 423.462 MiB, 0.09% gc time)`; note the sharply-reduced garbage collection.

Comment: Fixed the answer to remove the allocation (didn't notice the array was already passed as a parameter). If a function changes the value of the parameter it is a Julia custom to add a `!` to its name. This helps noticing exactly what I missed.

Comment: The rest of the time is probably spent in `dynam_serial`. Unless there is an algorithmic reason, there should be much less allocations.

Comment: @user1534219 Updated the answer with more optimizations

Comment: Thanks again, and sorry for not incorporating `!`. After incorporating `add_vecs_and_max!`, I was indeed able to reduce the number of allocations dramatically and eliminate garbage collection. However, the solution time increased to over 35 seconds (after running once already): `36.724082 seconds (5.09 k allocations: 500.627 KiB)`. After running `@profile`,  I saw that most of the time/backtraces was spent on `maxr = max(r[i],maxr)`, in `add_vecs_and_max!`.  So devectorizing seems to speed up the vector addition, but it slows down finding the maximum within the summed vector?

Comment: @user1534219 The long time spent on `max` is almost surely because of type instability which occurs when mixing Float32 and Float64 and Int. So make sure all the variables are the same, and better make it Float64, otherwise you need to make sure constant such as `-Inf` are `Float32(-Inf)`.

Comment: I went through and scrubbed any references to `Float32` or `Int32` in the functions and data constructions, and also made sure to declare function argument types as `Float64` and `Int64` just to be certain. I got the same performance. I then compared `findmax` in `array.jl` and `max` in `math.jl`. `findmax` does an initial empty array check for every value, whereas `max` does it twice, for the two arguments of `max`. Also, is it possible that when we're doing `max(r[i],maxr)`, time is taken to locate `r[i]`? Whereas in `findmax`, the comparison value is stored as a local.

Comment: Something is weird. There are still too many allocations in your benchmark (compared to my run). Have you tried copy-paste-ing my functions and using them directly? If you want to trace the problem together, post your recent code.

Comment: I copied and pasted both versions of input construction and functions, exactly as ran. Note that I also tried a `Float64` version of both the inputs and function argument declarations for the second/`findmax` version, but achieved poorer performance, around 40 seconds.

Comment: @user1534219 Did you try out the new update in the answer (the version without `Tv`)? Is it faster?

Comment: @user3580870 Yes, I did!! Here is the performance I got: `28.972583 seconds (9 allocations: 327.500 KiB)`. So thanks very much for those improvements. Here's the only mystery: When I use `Array{Float32}` and `Float32`, and allow any type of integer, here's the performance I get: `23.856429 seconds (9 allocations: 164.063 KiB)`. This is puzzling given that, as you say, modern CPU's are optimized for `Float64`. This is an old article, and specific to SIMD operations, but it suggests `Float32` could be faster in some circumstances: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vectorization-in-julia

Comment: @user1534219 I suppose the BLAS library is optimized enough to make the smaller memory footprint of Float32 give an advantage. In any case, it would be nice if you "accepted" the answer, and in general, the gentle users of stack-overflow like positive feedback.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, I just accepted and upvoted the answer. Really appreciate your help on this! Only was able to test the answer this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I copied-and-pasted, provided by Dan Getz above. I include the array and scalar definitions exactly as I ran them. Performance was: `39.507005 seconds (11 allocations: 486.891 KiB)` when running `@time  dynam_serial(E,gm,gz,beta,Zprob)`.

```
using SpecialFunctions
est_params = [.788,.288,.0034,.1519,.1615,.0041,.0077,.2,0.005,.7196]

r          = 0.015
tau        = 0.35
rho        =est_params[1]
sigma      =est_params[2]
delta      = 0.15
gamma      =est_params[3]
a_capital  =est_params[4]
lambda1    =est_params[5]
lambda2    =est_params[6]
s          =est_params[7]
theta      =est_params[8]
mu         =est_params[9]
p_bar_k_ss  =est_params[10]
beta  = (1+r)^(-1)
sigma_range = 4
gz = 19 #15 #19
gp = 29 #19 #29
gk = 37 #25 #37

lnz=collect(linspace(-sigma_range*sigma,sigma_range*sigma,gz))
z=exp.(lnz)

gk_m = fld(gk,2)
# Need to add mu somewhere to k_ss
k_ss =  (theta*(1-tau)/(r+delta))^(1/(1-theta))
k=cat(1,map(i->k_ss*((1-delta)^i),collect(1:gk_m)),map(i->k_ss/((1-delta)^i),collect(1:gk_m)))
insert!(k,gk_m+1,k_ss)
sort!(k)
p_bar=p_bar_k_ss*k_ss
p = collect(linspace(-p_bar/2,p_bar,gp))

#Tauchen
N     = length(z)
Z     = zeros(N,1)
Zprob = zeros(Float64,N,N)

Z[N]  = lnz[length(z)]
Z[1]  = lnz[1]

zstep = (Z[N] - Z[1]) / (N - 1)

for i=2:(N-1)
    Z[i] = Z[1] + zstep * (i - 1)
end

for a = 1 : N
    for b = 1 : N
      if b == 1
          Zprob[a,b] = 0.5*erfc(-((Z[1] - mu - rho * Z[a] + zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2))
      elseif b == N
          Zprob[a,b] = 1 - 0.5*erfc(-((Z[N] - mu - rho * Z[a] - zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2))
      else
          Zprob[a,b] = 0.5*erfc(-((Z[b] - mu - rho * Z[a] + zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2)) -
                       0.5*erfc(-((Z[b] - mu - rho * Z[a] - zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2))
      end
    end
end
# Collecting tauchen results in a 2 element array of linspace and array; [2] gets array
# Zprob=collect(tauchen(gz, rho, sigma, mu, sigma_range))[2]
Zcumprob=zeros(Float64,gz,gz)
# 2 in cumsum! denotes the 2nd dimension, i.e. columns
cumsum!(Zcumprob, Zprob,2)


gm = gk * gp

control=zeros(gm,2)
for i=1:gk
    control[(1+gp*(i-1)):(gp*i),1]=fill(k[i],(gp,1))
    control[(1+gp*(i-1)):(gp*i),2]=p
end
endog=copy(control)

E=Array(Float64,gm,gm,gz)
for h=1:gm
   for m=1:gm
       for j=1:gz
         # set the nonzero net debt indicator
          if endog[h,2]<0
             p_ind=1

          else
             p_ind=0
          end

           # set the investment indicator
            if (control[m,1]-(1-delta)*endog[h,1])!=0
               i_ind=1
            else
               i_ind=0
            end

            E[m,h,j] = (1-tau)*z[j]*(endog[h,1]^theta) + control[m,2]-endog[h,2]*(1+r*(1-tau))  +
                delta*endog[h,1]*tau-(control[m,1]-(1-delta)*endog[h,1]) -
                 (i_ind*gamma*endog[h,1]+endog[h,1]*(a_capital/2)*(((control[m,1]-(1-delta)*endog[h,1])/endog[h,1])^2)) +
                s*endog[h,2]*p_ind
            elem = E[m,h,j]
            if E[m,h,j]<0
                E[m,h,j]=elem+lambda1*elem-.5*lambda2*elem^2
            else
                E[m,h,j]=elem
            end
        end
    end
 end

function add_vecs_and_max!(gm::Int,r::Array{Float64},h::Int,j::Int,E::Array{Float64},
                           exp_v::Array{Float64},beta::Float64)
    maxr = -Inf
    @inbounds for i=1:gm            r[i] = E[i,h,j]+beta*exp_v[i,j]
        maxr = max(r[i],maxr)
    end
    return maxr
end

function dynam_serial(E::Array{Float64},gm::Int,gz::Int,
                      beta::Float64,Zprob::Array{Float64})
    v           = Array{Float64}(gm,gz)
    fill!(v,E[cld(gm,2),cld(gm,2),cld(gz,2)])
    Tv          = Array{Float64}(gm,gz)
    r           = Array{Float64}(gm)
    exp_v       = Array{Float64}(gm,gz)

    # Set parameters for the loop
    convcrit = 0.0001   # chosen convergence criterion
    diff = 1.0 # arbitrary initial value greater than convcrit
    while diff>convcrit
        A_mul_Bt!(exp_v,v,Zprob)
        diff = -Inf
        for h=1:gm
            for j=1:gz
                Tv[h,j]=add_vecs_and_max!(gm,r,h,j,E,exp_v,beta)
                diff = max(abs(Tv[h,j]-v[h,j]),diff)
            end
        end
        (v,Tv)=(Tv,v)
    end
    return v
end
```

Now, here's another version of the algorithm and inputs. The functions are similar to what Dan Getz suggested, except that I use `findmax` rather than an iterated `max` function to find the array maximum. In the input construction, I am using both `Float32` and mixing different bit-types together. However, I've consistently achieved better performance this way: `24.905569 seconds (1.81 k allocations: 46.829 MiB, 0.01% gc time)`. But it's not clear at all why.

```
using SpecialFunctions
est_params = [.788,.288,.0034,.1519,.1615,.0041,.0077,.2,0.005,.7196]

r          = 0.015
tau        = 0.35
rho        =est_params[1]
sigma      =est_params[2]
delta      = 0.15
gamma      =est_params[3]
a_capital  =est_params[4]
lambda1    =est_params[5]
lambda2    =est_params[6]
s          =est_params[7]
theta      =est_params[8]
mu         =est_params[9]
p_bar_k_ss  =est_params[10]
beta  = Float32((1+r)^(-1))
sigma_range = 4
gz = 19
gp = 29
gk = 37

lnz=collect(linspace(-sigma_range*sigma,sigma_range*sigma,gz))
z=exp(lnz)

gk_m = fld(gk,2)
# Need to add mu somewhere to k_ss
k_ss =  (theta*(1-tau)/(r+delta))^(1/(1-theta))
k=cat(1,map(i->k_ss*((1-delta)^i),collect(1:gk_m)),map(i->k_ss/((1-delta)^i),collect(1:gk_m)))
insert!(k,gk_m+1,k_ss)
sort!(k)
p_bar=p_bar_k_ss*k_ss
p = collect(linspace(-p_bar/2,p_bar,gp))

#Tauchen
N     = length(z)
Z     = zeros(N,1)
Zprob = zeros(Float32,N,N)

Z[N]  = lnz[length(z)]
Z[1]  = lnz[1]

zstep = (Z[N] - Z[1]) / (N - 1)

for i=2:(N-1)
    Z[i] = Z[1] + zstep * (i - 1)
end

for a = 1 : N
    for b = 1 : N
      if b == 1
          Zprob[a,b] = 0.5*erfc(-((Z[1] - mu - rho * Z[a] + zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2))
      elseif b == N
          Zprob[a,b] = 1 - 0.5*erfc(-((Z[N] - mu - rho * Z[a] - zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2))
      else
          Zprob[a,b] = 0.5*erfc(-((Z[b] - mu - rho * Z[a] + zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2)) -
                       0.5*erfc(-((Z[b] - mu - rho * Z[a] - zstep / 2) / sigma)/sqrt(2))
      end
    end
end
# Collecting tauchen results in a 2 element array of linspace and array; [2] gets array
# Zprob=collect(tauchen(gz, rho, sigma, mu, sigma_range))[2]
Zcumprob=zeros(Float32,gz,gz)
# 2 in cumsum! denotes the 2nd dimension, i.e. columns
cumsum!(Zcumprob, Zprob,2)


gm = gk * gp

control=zeros(gm,2)
for i=1:gk
    control[(1+gp*(i-1)):(gp*i),1]=fill(k[i],(gp,1))
    control[(1+gp*(i-1)):(gp*i),2]=p
end
endog=copy(control)

E=Array(Float32,gm,gm,gz)
for h=1:gm
   for m=1:gm
       for j=1:gz
         # set the nonzero net debt indicator
          if endog[h,2]<0
             p_ind=1

          else
             p_ind=0
          end

           # set the investment indicator
            if (control[m,1]-(1-delta)*endog[h,1])!=0
               i_ind=1
            else
               i_ind=0
            end

            E[m,h,j] = (1-tau)*z[j]*(endog[h,1]^theta) + control[m,2]-endog[h,2]*(1+r*(1-tau))  +
                delta*endog[h,1]*tau-(control[m,1]-(1-delta)*endog[h,1]) -
                 (i_ind*gamma*endog[h,1]+endog[h,1]*(a_capital/2)*(((control[m,1]-(1-delta)*endog[h,1])/endog[h,1])^2)) +
                s*endog[h,2]*p_ind
            elem = E[m,h,j]
            if E[m,h,j]<0
                E[m,h,j]=elem+lambda1*elem-.5*lambda2*elem^2
            else
                E[m,h,j]=elem
            end
        end
    end
 end

 function add_vecs!(gm::Int,r::Array{Float32},h::Int,j::Int,E::Array{Float32},
                   exp_v::Array{Float32},beta::Float32)

     @inbounds @views for i=1:gm
         r[i]=E[i,h,j] + beta*exp_v[i,j]
     end
     return r
 end

 function dynam_serial(E::Array{Float32},gm::Int,gz::Int,beta::Float32,Zprob::Array{Float32})
     v           = Array{Float32}(gm,gz)
     fill!(v,E[cld(gm,2),cld(gm,2),cld(gz,2)])

     Tv          = Array{Float32}(gm,gz)

     # Set parameters for the loop
     convcrit = 0.0001   # chosen convergence criterion
     diff = 1.00000          # arbitrary initial value greater than convcrit
     iter=0
     exp_v=Array{Float32}(gm,gz)

     r=Array{Float32}(gm)

     while diff>convcrit


       A_mul_Bt!(exp_v,v,Zprob)

       for h=1:gm
         for j=1:gz
           Tv[h,j]=findmax(add_vecs!(gm,r,h,j,E,exp_v,beta))[1]
         end
       end
       diff = maximum(abs,Tv - v)
       (v,Tv)=(Tv,v)
     end
     return v
 end
```

Comment: Turns out `findmax` really is faster.

Comment: Added another update to my answer with a little more optimization. To further increase speed, a new direction should be tried, or going parallel can be considered.

Comment: Dan, thanks again for your help from way back! I moved on to other issues with my algorithm, but I'm now going back to wringing out better performance via parallel processing with this newly-posted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091791/julia-pmap-speed-parallel-processing