# Julia pmap speed - parallel processing - dynamic programming

Tags: matrix, parallel-processing, julia, dynamic-programming, pmap

I am trying to speed up filling in a matrix for a dynamic programming problem in Julia (v0.6.0), and I can't seem to get much extra speed from using `pmap`. This is related to this question I posted almost a year ago: [Filling a matrix using parallel processing in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178227/filling-a-matrix-using-parallel-processing-in-julia). I was able to speed up serial processing with some great help then, and I'm now trying to get extra speed from parallel processing tools in Julia.

For the serial processing case, I was using a 3-dimensional matrix (essentially a set of equally-sized matrices, indexed by the 1st-dimension) and iterating over the 1st-dimension. I wanted to give `pmap` a try, though, to more efficiently iterate over the set of matrices.

Here is the code setup. To use `pmap` with the `v_iter` function below, I converted the three dimensional matrix into a dictionary object, with the dictionary keys equal to the index values in the 1st dimension (`v_dict` in the code below, with `gcc` equal to the 1st-dimension size). The `v_iter` function takes other dictionary objects (`E_opt_dict` and `gridpoint_m_dict` below) as additional inputs:

```
function v_iter(a,b,c)
   diff_v = 1
   while diff_v>convcrit
     diff_v = -Inf

     #These lines efficiently multiply the value function by the Markov transition matrix, using the A_mul_B function
     exp_v       = zeros(Float64,gkpc,1)
     A_mul_B!(exp_v,a[1:gkpc,:],Zprob[1,:])
     for j=2:gz
       temp=Array{Float64}(gkpc,1)
       A_mul_B!(temp,a[(j-1)*gkpc+1:(j-1)*gkpc+gkpc,:],Zprob[j,:])
       exp_v=hcat(exp_v,temp)
     end    

     #This tries to find the optimal value of v
     for h=1:gm
       for j=1:gz
         oldv = a[h,j]
         newv = (1-tau)*b[h,j]+beta*exp_v[c[h,j],j]
         a[h,j] = newv
         diff_v = max(diff_v, oldv-newv, newv-oldv)
       end
     end
   end
end

gz =  9  
gp =  13  
gk =  17  
gcc =  5  
gm    = gk * gp * gcc * gz
gkpc  = gk * gp * gcc
gkp = gk*gp
beta  = ((1+0.015)^(-1))
tau        = 0.35
Zprob = [0.43 0.38 0.15 0.03 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00; 0.05 0.47 0.35 0.11 0.02 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00; 0.01 0.10 0.50 0.30 0.08 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00; 0.00 0.02 0.15 0.51 0.26 0.06 0.01  0.00 0.00; 0.00 0.00 0.03 0.21 0.52 0.21 0.03 0.00 0.00 ; 0.00 0.00  0.01  0.06 0.26 0.51 0.15 0.02 0.00 ; 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.08 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.01 ; 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.02 0.11 0.35 0.47 0.05; 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.03 0.15 0.38 0.43]
convcrit = 0.001   # chosen convergence criterion

E_opt                  = Array{Float64}(gcc,gm,gz)    
fill!(E_opt,10.0)

gridpoint_m   = Array{Int64}(gcc,gm,gz)
fill!(gridpoint_m,fld(gkp,2)) 

v_dict=Dict(i => zeros(Float64,gm,gz) for i=1:gcc)
E_opt_dict=Dict(i => E_opt[i,:,:] for i=1:gcc)
gridpoint_m_dict=Dict(i => gridpoint_m[i,:,:] for i=1:gcc)
```

For parallel processing, I executed the following two commands:

```
wp = CachingPool(workers())
addprocs(3)
pmap(wp,v_iter,values(v_dict),values(E_opt_dict),values(gridpoint_m_dict))
```

...which produced this performance:

`135.626417 seconds (3.29 G allocations: 57.152 GiB, 3.74% gc time)`

I then tried to serial process instead:

```
for i=1:gcc
    v_iter(v_dict[i],E_opt_dict[i],gridpoint_m_dict[i])
end
```

...and received better performance.

```
128.263852 seconds (3.29 G allocations: 57.101 GiB, 4.53% gc time)
```

This also gives me about the same performance as running `v_iter` on the original 3-dimensional objects:

```
v=zeros(Float64,gcc,gm,gz)
for i=1:gcc
    v_iter(v[i,:,:],E_opt[i,:,:],gridpoint_m[i,:,:])
end
```

I know that parallel processing involves setup time, but when I increase the value of `gcc`, I still get about equal processing time for serial and parallel. This seems like a good candidate for parallel processing, since there is no need for messaging between the workers! But I can't seem to make it work efficiently.

Comment: Dear @user1534219 your code is extremely long and providing an answer here would be no useful for others. Can you filter out only the part relevant to your question (e.g. by providing a 10-line basic example instead of almost 200 lines that you have now)

Comment: Hi Przemyslaw Szufel, thanks for your input. I edited the code considerably, by simply putting in values for the `Zprob` Markov transition matrix instead of the function to construct that matrix...the performance changed a bit, since I rounded the numbers in that matrix. I also added the words "dynamic programming" to the question title so readers were aware of the question focus. Dynamic programming problems are pretty common in economics, finance, and operations research.

Answer (score 1):

You create the `CachingPool` before adding the worker processes. Hence your caching pool passed to `pmap` tells it to use just a single worker. 
You can simply check it by running `wp.workers` you will see something like `Set([1])`.
Hence it should be:

`addprocs(3)
wp = CachingPool(workers())`

You could also consider running Julia `-p` command line parameter e.g. `julia -p 3` and then you can skip the `addprocs(3)` command.

On top of that your `for` and `pmap` loops are not equivalent. The Julia `Dict` object is a hashmap and similar to other languages does not offer anything like element order. Hence in your for loop you are guaranteed to get the same matching `i`-th element while with the `values` the ordering of values does not need to match the original ordering (and you can have different order for each of those three variables in the `pmap` loop). 
Since the keys for your `Dicts` are just numbers from `1` up to `gcc` you should simply use arrays instead. You can use generators very similar to Python. For an example instead of 

`v_dict=Dict(i => zeros(Float64,gm,gz) for i=1:gcc)`

use

`v_dict_a = [zeros(Float64,gm,gz)  for i=1:gcc]`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response! I do appreciate it.  I will definitely give these suggestions a try.  As for the hash...I want to use `pmap` to loop over a collection of matrices, so that each can be modified separately. I thought that the `Dict` object was the way to construct this collection, but your response suggests this was misguided. Is there some other object you can suggest for this purpose? I'd like to avoid `SharedArrays` if possible, especially since there is no messaging required among workers.

Comment: @user1534219, I edited the response. Avoiding `SharedArrays` is always a good idea because it brings a significant level of complexity to your code.

Comment: Przemyslaw Szufel, thanks for your help!!  With parallel processing, I got the time down to 54 seconds, vs. 125 seconds with serial processing, using the generator you suggested. The only additional change I made was to make the `v_iter` function an anonymous function, per the advice here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/everywhere-and-pmap-inside-of-a-function/5405/3; otherwise, I would have had to sprinkle  `@everywhere` around the code, to feed functions and data to the workers.

Comment: Ugh, I spoke too soon. The `v_a` matrix, unfortunately, wasn't modified at all when I ran the above code with all of the changes suggested.

Comment: I *think* the problem here is that the workers can't modify the same object, unless it's an object like a `SharedArray`. The original `Dict` object I used was useful, inasmuch as it just created a mapping to completely separate objects. However, as you noted, the `Dict` object doesn't offer the element order that I require! So it seems like I need an ordered pointer to distinct objects, to make `pmap` work in this context.

Comment: I wrote you to replace `Dict`s  with `Array`s - and put a simple generator code that does it. Didn't it work for you?

Comment: For modifying the same object by many workers you can also use `ParallelDataTransfer.jl`. But unless there is something very specific about your sweep you do not need it.

Comment: I did replace `Dict` with `Array`, but the `v_a` array was in its original form after executing `pmap`. I had earlier answered my own question with your suggested changes, but then deleted the answer, once I realized the problem with `v_a`. I will now undelete it so you can see exactly what I did. Thanks for all your help! I see from your profile you are an econ professor; it's great to have the help of someone who works on similar problems.

Comment: Hi Przemyslaw, I don't suppose you have an idea about why the `Array` object `v_a` isn't getting modified in the answer I provided below? It's inputted as argument `a` in the `v_iter` function. I'm running a dynamic principal-agent model, and I'm trying to parallel process over the principal's choices.

Comment: @user1534219 you can not pass "by reference" to a remote process. Instead of that return the value in the `v_iter`. The `pmap` will return a `Dict` object with all the results.

Comment: @user1534219 on top of that - you should reduce your examples to 5-10-lines rather than pasting here all of your production code....

Comment: @Prezemyslaw Szufel, thanks, I returned a value in `v_iter`, and modified my answer below to reflect that. It now works as intended, thank you!! In terms of shortening the examples to 5-10 lines: I definitely want to make sure this question-and-answer is useful to many users. I originally wanted to show an example of parallel processing for value function iteration; however, it does require more lines than required, than if the goal is simply to show how to parallel process array modification. Should I modify the example to simply reflect the latter, and retitle the question, in your opinion?

Comment: I would suggest you to rebuild the question around a simple example - e.g. one that does parameter sweep over some one-line monte carlo simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Przemyslaw Szufeul's helpful advice, I've placed below the code that properly executes parallel processing. After running it once, I achieved substantial improvement in running time: 
`77.728264 seconds (181.20 k allocations: 12.548 MiB)`

In addition to reordering the `wp` command and using the generator Przemyslaw recommended, I also recast `v_iter` as an anonymous function, in order to avoid having to sprinkle `@everywhere` around the code to feed functions and data to the workers.

I also added `return a` to the `v_iter` function, and set `v_a` below equal to the output of `pmap`, since you cannot pass by reference to a remote object.

```
addprocs(3)
v_iter = function(a,b,c)
   diff_v = 1
   while diff_v>convcrit
     diff_v = -Inf

     #These lines efficiently multiply the value function by the Markov transition matrix, using the A_mul_B function
     exp_v       = zeros(Float64,gkpc,1)
     A_mul_B!(exp_v,a[1:gkpc,:],Zprob[1,:])
     for j=2:gz
       temp=Array{Float64}(gkpc,1)
       A_mul_B!(temp,a[(j-1)*gkpc+1:(j-1)*gkpc+gkpc,:],Zprob[j,:])
       exp_v=hcat(exp_v,temp)
     end    

     #This tries to find the optimal value of v
     for h=1:gm
       for j=1:gz
         oldv = a[h,j]
         newv = (1-tau)*b[h,j]+beta*exp_v[c[h,j],j]
         a[h,j] = newv
         diff_v = max(diff_v, oldv-newv, newv-oldv)
       end
     end
   end
  return a
end

gz =  9  
gp =  13  
gk =  17  
gcc =  5  
gm    = gk * gp * gcc * gz
gkpc  = gk * gp * gcc
gkp   =gk*gp
beta  = ((1+0.015)^(-1))
tau        = 0.35
Zprob = [0.43 0.38 0.15 0.03 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00; 0.05 0.47 0.35 0.11 0.02 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00; 0.01 0.10 0.50 0.30 0.08 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00; 0.00 0.02 0.15 0.51 0.26 0.06 0.01  0.00 0.00; 0.00 0.00 0.03 0.21 0.52 0.21 0.03 0.00 0.00 ; 0.00 0.00  0.01  0.06 0.26 0.51 0.15 0.02 0.00 ; 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.08 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.01 ; 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.02 0.11 0.35 0.47 0.05; 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.03 0.15 0.38 0.43]
convcrit = 0.001   # chosen convergence criterion

E_opt                  = Array{Float64}(gcc,gm,gz)    
fill!(E_opt,10.0)

gridpoint_m   = Array{Int64}(gcc,gm,gz)
fill!(gridpoint_m,fld(gkp,2)) 

v_a=[zeros(Float64,gm,gz) for i=1:gcc]
E_opt_a=[E_opt[i,:,:] for i=1:gcc]
gridpoint_m_a=[gridpoint_m[i,:,:] for i=1:gcc]

wp = CachingPool(workers())
v_a = pmap(wp,v_iter,v_a,E_opt_a,gridpoint_m_a)
```